# Inputed elements of the array are being recognized as type string instead of type float

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

i'm trying to write a code that sorts 3 numbers inputed by the user (i cant use the sort() function) for a college activity. I tried using parseFloat() to make it work but it still outputs an array of strings.

```
var readlineSync = require ('readline-sync');

var numeros = [];
var i = 0;
var aux = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    numeros[i] = readlineSync.question ('Digite o numero ' + (i+1) +': ');
    parseFloat(numeros[i]);
}

console.log(numeros)

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (j = i+1; j < 3; j++){
        if( numeros[i] > numeros[j]) {
                aux = numeros[i];
                numeros[i] = numeros [j];
                numeros[j] = aux;
            }
    }
}

console.log(numeros);
```

Any idea on how i can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `parseFloat(numeros[i]);` but you never assign the value to anything

```
const input = readlineSync.question ('Digite o numero ' + (i+1) +': ');
numeros[i] = parseFloat(input);
```